# XENAPI VLAN not getting flown to slave node if created on master node

Tags: python, virtualization, citrix, xen, hypervisor

I am trying to create a VLAN on host from xenapi python library. VLAN is getting created by following way,

```
>>> network = session.xenapi.network.create({'name_label': 'VLAN1280', 'name_description': 'VLAN1280', 'other_config': {}, 'bridge': '', 'MTU': '1500'})
>>> pif = session.xenapi.PIF.get_by_uuid("a733dc21-4e9e-9a13-0ba6-8cf1db29a985")
>>> vlan = session.xenapi.VLAN.create(pif, "1280", network)
```

Session is only getting created for masternode as xenapi does not allow to connect to slave node.

By the above code snippet, VLAN is getting created only on Master Node.
[image: Image of vlan created on master node with VLAN and NIC attached.]

However, this does not getting flown to slave node with VLAN tag and NIC information. only NETWORK name is getting reflected but not NIC and VLAN information.
[image: Image of VLAN created with improper information of NIC and VLAN tag.]

I'd like to mention, when we try to create a VLAN network from xencenter application, it is getting created on master node as well on slave node with proper information.

Can someone please guide me/help me out for this issue?

Comment: Whatever you do in XenCenter in fact just calls xenapi functions. Hence, everything clicked in GUI can be achieved programatically. I have never had NIC/VLAN problems so I can't help you directly solve your problem.

Comment: @Artur Exactly, everything that we do from xencenter can be achieved my xenapi python calls as well. Could you please check this once nad give it a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution for this problem. 
Just replace

```
vlan = session.xenapi.VLAN.create(pif, "1280", network)
```

by

```
 vlan = session.xenapi.pool.create_VLAN_from_PIF(pif, network, "1280")
```

This will create VLAN on all nodes in the cluster.